# Get specific message on regex validation

Tags: java, android, regex

Is this possible to get specific message on regex validation?

**For eg.**

Our regex is `'[0-9]{1,5}'` and user enters `'123456'` then message like `'max characters exceeded'`
and if user enters `'abcd'` then message like `'invalid characters'` should be displayed.

Does anyone have any idea??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure you're gonna need separate conditional statements for that

Comment: I get the regex from the server so i have to validate the input on the client side and display an informational message.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "automatic" solution. You can however hold several regular expressions and try to match your input against these regexes holding error message per regex. For example:

```
Pattern correctInput = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,5}");
Pattern onlyDigits = Pattern.compile("^\\d*$");

if (!correctInput.matcher(input).find()) {
    return onlyDigits.matcher(input).find()) ? "wrong number of characters" : "invalid characters";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Is it possible to split a regex?? I mean `'[0-9]{1,5}'` to `[1-9]` and `'[0-9]{1,5}'`

Comment: I am sorry, your question is unclear. What do you mean when you say: "split regex?" Create 2 separate regexes?

Comment: You can create as many regular expressions as you want. You can also put them input map where pattern is a key and error message is a value and write generic code that tries to apply pattern until one matches and gets appropriate error message.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php, you can do it something like:

```
if (!preg_match('/[0-9]{1,5}/', $agent)) {

    if(!preg_match('/^\d+/', $agent)) { //if not numbers
        echo 'invalid characters';
    } else {
        echo 'max characters';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But i am looking for a java solution. and your answer is same as the @AlexR's ..